# Flex 3 LinkButton width: Distorted Skin Image

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am using linkButtons with a background skin inside a linkBar with a dataProvider.  A couple of the labels from the linkButtons are too long and distort the linkButton skin.  How can I make all of the linkButtons labels the same width?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an item renderer to render a set of data the way you wish.

You can include most of the components in custom renderers.

Check out the following articles

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html

and

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-using-item-renderers

Hope that helps!

Cheers,

Ernani

Answer (score 0):

If you want the width to be based on the text then you have to pre-measure your text to figure out the max width and then pass that width into the itemRenderers.